# Heap memory clarification

Tags: c, typedef, heap-memory

I am having issue with the code that i provided.
I am not quit sure what is wrong with my code. I would greatly appreciate if you can clearing point out what is wrong with my code. basically, i am trying to allocate memory for person height and weight and calculate BMI.

edited: When i run this code, i would like it to ask for user name, get user name. ask user weight and height and calculate then print result but when i execute this code. all i am getting is

**H has a BMI of = inf**

Thanks,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {

    float heightInMeters;
    int weightInMeters;
}Person;
float bodyMassIndex (Person*p)
{
    return (*p).weightInKilos / ((*p).heightInMeters*(*p).heightInMeters);
}

int main()
{
    Person *x = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    Person weightInKilos;
    Person heightInMeters;
    char name;

    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    sleep(1);

    printf("Please enter your weight in Kilos\n");
    scanf("%d", &weightInKilos);
    sleep(1);

    printf("Please enter your height in Meters\n");
    scanf("%f", &heightInMeters);

    float xBMI = bodyMassIndex(x);
    printf("%s has a BMI of = %.2f\n", &name, xBMI);

    free(x);

    x = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will be more likely to get help if you put some effort in yourself. Like, what's wrong with what you have? Compile errors? Runtime errors? Wrong output (wrong how?)?

Comment: Pretty much *everything* is wrong. Slow down a little, do some reading. Walk before you run.

Comment: `(*p).heightInMeters` would be far better written as `p->heightInMeters`.  There's also really no call to dynamically allocate the structure; it would be more sensible to use a local variable of structure type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the struct definition, `int weightInMeters;` should be `int weightInKilos;`.

This line doesn't do anything:

```
(*x).weightInKilos;
```

It is like writing: `1 + 1;` . What was your intention here?  (Technically this line causes undefined behaviour for evaluating an uninitialized variable).

```
char name;
scanf("%s", &name);
```

The declaration `char name;` means that `name` is a single character.  But `scanf("%s"` tries to read several characters. This will cause a buffer overflow with unpredictable consequences. Replace those with:

```
char name[100];
scanf("%100s", name);
```

This line:

```
scanf("%d", &weightInKilos);
```

I assume you meant

```
scanf("%d", &x->weightInKilos);
```

Finally, in this line:

```
printf("%s has a BMI of = %.2f\n", &name, xBMI);
```

`&name` should just be `name`.

Comment: `scanf("%100s", name);` should be `scanf("%99s", name);`

Comment: I declared (*x).weightInKilos because originally the book has it as (*x).weightInKilos = 81; but i didn't want a constant value so i thought i can change it up a little by adding the scanf to get input from user.

I am just starting out.

also the book showed scanf as scanf("xxx", &name);
Why omit the operand sign &?

Comment: @user2304236 "%s" is to request `char*`.

Comment: Your `(*x).weightInKilos;` isn't a declaration, it's just a statement that does nothing. The line `Person *x;` declared `x`, and the definition of `Person` declared `weightInKilos`.

Comment: When you deal with an array, `name` is a shorthand for writing `&name[0]`.  So it is like `scanf("%100s", &name[0])`. The way that `scanf("%s` works is that it expects a pointer to the first character of a block of characters; and it writes the input into that block.